# How to use a single function for members with same types C++

Tags: c++

```
string getstroke(){
    return line1;
}
string getstroke2(){
    return line2;
}
string getstroke3(){
    return line3;
}
string getstroke4(){
    return line4;
}
```

I want to use `getstroke()` for all of my string members with out making another function with the same 'function' with a different function name, how do I do it?

Comment: Have you thought about adding an int parameter to the function? http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/ If you do that you can use a switch or an if-then-else to return the proper line.

Answer (score 3):

I guess a quick way would be to have an argument to your function. That way you can choose which line you want to return.

```
string getstroke(int line){
    if(line == 1)
        return line1;
    if(line == 2)
        return line2;
    if(line == 3)
        return line3;
    if(line == 4)
        return line4;
}
```

You could also use a switch statement.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use templates.

```
template <int N> string getstroke();
template <> string getstroke<1>() { return line1; }
template <> string getstroke<2>() { return line2; }
template <> string getstroke<3>() { return line3; }
template <> string getstroke<4>() { return line4; }
```

Since it will also generate four functions. Note that `N` cannot be a number you do not know at compile time.